# Getting Releasing unheld lock CriticalSection in Windows C++ code

Tags: c++, winapi, critical-section

I'm getting a warning "Releasing unheld lock 'csCriticalSection'" at the 2nd try below.

Here is my code, but without all the ADO code. I don't know why I'm getting this warning, because if the `Execute()` function fails, the `catch` will run a `LeaveCriticalSection` function. If the `Execute()` function succeeds, I call `LeaveCriticalSection`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <conio.h>

CRITICAL_SECTION csCriticalSection;

_ConnectionPtr connectioncreate = nullptr;
_RecordsetPtr recordset = nullptr;

int main()
{
InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&csCriticalSection, 4000);

// *** all ADO code here ***
//
// *** all ADO code here ***

BOOL bRanLeaveCriticalSection = FALSE;
try
    {
    EnterCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection);
    // Run an SQL command with ADO.
    /*
    connectioncreate->BeginTrans();
    connectioncreate->Execute(sSQL.data(), nullptr, adCmdText);
    connectioncreate->CommitTrans();
    */
    LeaveCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection);
    bRanLeaveCriticalSection = TRUE;
    }

catch (CONST _com_error& err)
    {
    connectioncreate->CommitTrans();
    if (bRanLeaveCriticalSection == FALSE)
        LeaveCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection);
    }


try
    {
    // From compiler at the next line "if (recordset)":
    // Warning  C26117  Releasing unheld lock 'csCriticalSection'
    if (recordset)
        if (recordset->State == adStateOpen)
            recordset->Close();
    }
catch (CONST _com_error& err)
    {
    err;
    }

_getch();
}
```

Can anyone help me to for the reason why I'm getting this warning and how to ***fix it***?

Comment: You're missing [`InitializeCriticalSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection) before anything that actually uses that thing. And to be honest, committing a transaction *within* a `_com_error` exception handler is arguably madness in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig ...added, thanks.

Comment: FWIW, if you compile with Visual Studio, ATL provides an RAII smart class that avoids many issues : CComAutoCriticalSection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomautocriticalsection-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `csCriticalSection` before using it, eg:

```
...
CRITICAL_SECTION csCriticalSection;
...

int main()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection); // <-- ADD THIS
    ...
    DeleteCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection); // <-- ADD THIS
}
```

But also, you really shouldn't be using `bRanLeaveCriticalSection` at all, this is just bad code design.

You can use a [`__try/__finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-finally-statement?view=msvc-170) block instead (if your compiler supports that), eg:

```
...
CRITICAL_SECTION csCriticalSection;
...

int main()
{
    ...

    try
        {
        EnterCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection);
        __try
            {
            // Run an SQL command with ADO.
            }
        __finally
            {
            LeaveCriticalSection(&csCriticalSection);
            }
        }
    catch (CONST _com_error& err)
        {
        ...
        }

    ...
}
```

However, the *best* option is to use an RAII wrapper instead, let it call `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()` for you, eg:

```
struct CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION &m_cs;

    CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK(CRITICAL_SECTION &cs) : m_cs(cs) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    ~CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK() {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
};

...

CRITICAL_SECTION csCriticalSection;

int main()
{
    ...

    try
        {
        CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock(csCriticalSection);
        // Run an SQL command with ADO.
        }
    catch (CONST _com_error& err)
        {
        ...
        }

    ...
}
```

Or better, use a C++ [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) instead, with a proper RAII lock such as [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), eg:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

...

int main()
{
    try
        {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        // Run an SQL command with ADO.
        }
    catch (CONST _com_error& err)
        {
        ...
        }

    ...
}
```

Comment: So after I call `CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock(csCriticalSection);`, when it leaves the `try` block, it calls the destructor `~CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK()`?

Comment: It is a stack object.  Any stack object gets cleaned up at end of scope, guaranteed.  Even in the event of an exception.  That is the foundation of RAII.  It is "fire-and-forget"

Comment: @JeffR yes, that is exactly what happens

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice...I'm going to clean up my code and use mutexes instead of the csCriticalSection. So much easier and cleaner. Question: if I'm creating a lock mutex around `_wfopen_s/fwprintf_s/fclose`, code, and other threads are trying to also write to the same file, the mutex will pause them until the mutex goes out of scope, correct?

Comment: @JeffR When the lock goes out of scope, not the mutex itself, but yes. Assuming you are locking/unlocking the same mutex object each time and not creating a new mutex object each time.